# Where can I find a download link for Amazon Alexa for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, amazon

Where can I find a download link for Amazon Alexa for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: There's an Alexa client based on Java and Node that you can use. The project features [installation instructions for Debian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-raspberry-pi) but should work very similarly on a desktop machine with Ubuntu (minus all the remote access SSH and VNC stuff).

Comment: @DavidFoerster link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Alexa is not available for desktops. It's only available on Kindle Fire, Android, and iOS. Instead, you might want to go to alexa.amazon.com to control Echo from a computer. Also, alexa.amazon.com is vastly superior to the Amazon Alexa app but Amazon has been very quiet about it.. But if you want to use Alexa with your computer, go to alexa.amazon.com

Source:

1. https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201602060
2. http://www.howtogeek.com/243364/how-to-control-your-amazon-echo-from-the-web-instead-of-a-cramped-smartphone-app/

Comment: How do I turn on the mic to start speaking to Alexa from the website?